# What SHOULDN'T Django's admin interface be used for?

Tags: python, django, administration

I've been applying Django's automatic administration capabilities to some applications who had previously been very difficult to administer.  I'm thinking of a lot of ways to apply it to other applications we use (including using it to replace some internal apps altogether).  Before I go overboard though, is there anything in particular I *shouldn't* use it for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User-specific privileges. I myself had been trying to work it into that-- some of the new (and at least at the time, undocumented) features (from newforms-admin) make it actually possible. Depending on how fine you want the control to be, though, you can end up getting very, very deep into the Django/admin internals. Just because you can doesn't mean you should-- it's easier and less fragile to do so with a custom admin app.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you shouldn't use the admin for access by people you don't really trust. Even though there's plenty of flexibility in terms of locking things down and controlling access (much more so since Django 1.0), the admin is still designed on the assumption that the people using it are trusted members of your staff.